# Hikari getconnection is slow even though there are more connections than threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I have an application that reads messages from IBM MQ, processes them and writes data to an Oracle db.

The app is configured to have 6 concurrent Threads (should process max 6 messages concurrently if I understand right) and a minimum and maxium of 12 connections in the connection pool.

As a test, I write 30 messages to the queue, that do quite time consuming db operations. As there are only 6 threads and 12 connections, from my understanding there should still always be an available connection for a new thread.

But I am consistently seeing getConnection take 300ms+.

Here's the relevant part of the config:

```
spring:
  jms:
    cache.enabled: false
    listener:
      concurrency: 1
      max-concurrency: 6
   datasource:
    driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url: "[dbUrl]"
    username: "user"
    password: "pw"
    hikari.minimum-idle: 12 
    hikari.maximum-pool-size: 12
```

I am using Spring 5.2.5 with Spring Boot 2.2.6.

What am I missing? I was expecting getConnection to always return within a few ms even though the db operations might be time consuming?